# Is there a solution for getting machine 1 to turn off after sensor 2 is activated in my ladder-logic system?

Tags: ladder-logic

Can someone help me?
I can't solve this problem.
Sensor 1 activates when a box passes, and activates machine 1.
After 3 seconds, sensor 2 should activate, and machine 1 should deactivate.
But some error is occurring and machine 1 is never turned off.
TON timer loops and never activates Sensor 2
Does anyone know how to solve?

I'm using OpenPLC Editor

[image: Ladder Logic screenshot]

Thanks

I'm trying to make machine 1 stop via sensor 2.
Another thing, do you know how I can loop this system? To capture more boxes?

Answer (score 1):

IF `SENSOR_1` is still `TRUE` when the timer completes, then `Machine_1` is turning off for one cycle.

Here's what's happening:

1. `TON.Q` becomes `TRUE`, which turns on `SENSOR_2`.
2. `MACHINE_1` becomes `FALSE` because `SENSOR_2` is not `FALSE`
3. `TON` is reset because `MACHINE_1` is not `TRUE`
4. `TON.Q` becomes `FALSE` because the timer is not active.
5. `SENSOR_2` becomes `FALSE` because `TON.Q` is `FALSE`
6. `MACHINE_1` becomes `TRUE` because `SENSOR_2` is `FALSE` and ***`SENSOR_1` is still `TRUE`***
7. `TON` starts timing
8. Repeat forever.

The system should loop as long as the first sensor turns off while the timer is running. For robustness, I recommend adding logic to verify that the sensor turns off before you allow `MACHINE_1` to turn back on.